# How to create a Set of type 'Node' rather than 'Node+Element', containing a single node via ABAQUS scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

I am currently working on the FE analysis of a rectangular brick and mortar RVE. I plan to apply **PBC** on all edges. For that I need to create a Set of type 'Node' for each node along the boundary edges. Then I have to apply an equation constraint for corresponding nodes on opposite edges [(trying to Follow this video here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPiYgXEnl3Q&list=PL0en87H2H2m0J_m10q7JwkpbWNxrJK0oH&index=4). In the Equation Constraint dialog box, we can select sets of type 'Node' or 'Geometry'.

I wrote a script file in which I parametrized all the parameters defining the RVE. I kept the **edge seed as 0.01** and the **element type as CPS8R** (quadratic quadrilateral element). From this I know the exact number of nodes and their coordinates of my nodes along the boundaries.

```
tol = minseed/200   # tol=tolerance, where minseed = 0.01 (edge seed size)

Num_LE = 487        # Number of Left Edge Nodes
Num_RE = Num_LE     # ... ... Right Edge Nodes
Num_TE = 1643       # ... ... Top Edge Nodes
Num_BE = Num_TE     # ... ... Bottom Edge Nodes

AllNodes = mod.parts['RVE'].nodes

# Node Set Generation (Needs to be rectified, it is creating a set of type node+element rather than a set of type node)
for i in range(0, Num_LE):
    mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='LeftNode-'+str(i+1), nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox(0-tol, (i+1)*0.25*minseed-tol, 0, 0+tol, (i+1)*0.25*minseed+tol, 0))

for i in range(0, Num_RE):
    mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='RightNode-'+str(i+1), nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox(LRVE-tol, (i+1)*0.25*minseed-tol, 0, LRVE+tol, (i+1)*0.25*minseed+tol, 0))

for i in range(0, Num_TE):
    mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='TopNode-'+str(i+1), nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox((i+1)*0.25*minseed-tol, BRVE-tol, 0, (i+1)*0.25*minseed+tol, BRVE+tol, 0))

for i in range(0, Num_BE):
    mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='BottomNode-'+str(i+1), nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox((i+1)*0.25*minseed-tol, 0-tol, 0, (i+1)*0.25*minseed+tol, 0+tol, 0))

mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='BRNode', nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox(LRVE-tol, 0-tol, 0, LRVE+tol, 0+tol, 0))
mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='BLNode', nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox(0-tol, 0-tol, 0, 0+tol, 0+tol, 0))
mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='TLNode', nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox(0-tol, BRVE-tol, 0, 0+tol, BRVE+tol, 0))
mod.rootAssembly.Set(name='TRNode', nodes=AllNodes.getByBoundingBox(LRVE-tol, BRVE-tol, 0, LRVE+tol, BRVE+tol, 0))
```

The sets are being created when I run the script file in ABAQUS but when I go into Mesh module -> Object: Assembly, Tools -> Set -> Manager, I see that the sets created from the script are of type 'Node+Element' [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYDY6.png) while I expected them to be created as type 'Node'

Is there a something that I am missing or is there a better way to achieve the same? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide full script? It would be of a great help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for the reply. I have overcome the problem by using another method; by using edges and then extracting the node coordinates and labels from them. I was worried as my model had a large number of edges and I wanted to use the getByBoundingBox() method. But I had to resort to the edge method (video hyperlink in the posted question). Still, if you are interested in how it is done, I will share the script